# Eclipse git and ssh-agent

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, ssh-agent

I use eclipse with git (egit).

I would like to make use of my ssh-agent so I can push from eclipse. Does anybody know how to set up egit to use ssh-agent?

background: I can't upload my key to eclipse as my keys are on a cryptostick. My ssh-agent can loaded with the help of opensc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update June 2016 (4 years later): [Gunnar Wagenknecht](https://stackoverflow.com/users/275347/gunnar-wagenknecht) now mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396405/eclipse-git-and-ssh-agent/13398657#comment63461576_13398657):

> It's now possible in [Eclipse Neon](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/neon) with project [`eclipseguru/eclipse-jsch-agent-proxy`](https://github.com/eclipseguru/eclipse-jsch-agent-proxy), an Eclipse ssh-agent and Pageant support.

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipseguru/eclipse-jsch-agent-proxy/gh-pages/images/ssh-agent-preferences.png]

---

A workaround for older Eclipse versions is to use the native OS SSH client instead of the Eclipse built-in one by setting `GIT_SSH` environment variable:

```
export GIT_SSH=/usr/bin/ssh
```

(See [EGit SSH configuration](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Eclipse_SSH_Configuration) and [EGit FAQ, SSH Config](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#SSH_config))

Comment: @gautamvegeta you can try (not tested myself) https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=179924#c28

Comment: The repository/plugin is no longer maintained. :-(

Comment: @ST-DDT 7 years later, I am not chocked :) https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=541274 might include more up-to-date (2019) references.

Comment: Note that (as of Q1/2021) OS-provided ssh agents (such as seahorse on Ubuntu) are still not supported on Linux workstations; see: https://www.eclipse.org/lists/egit-dev/msg04781.html

Comment: @sxc731 That is too bad. I hope those agents will be supported soon.

Answer (score 10):

In your eclipse startup script or `.profile` (or wherever) add `export GIT_SSH=/usr/bin/ssh` before starting eclipse. Then eclipse uses default ssh which uses ssh agent and you cann run pull and push commands within eclipse even if your key is on a smartcard.

Edit: GIT_SSH is interpreted by eclipse's egit, but also by the stand-alone git. Setting it to `/usr/bin/ssh` sets it to the default value for stand-alone git, so only egit will change it's behavior.

Comment: If you set `GIT_SSH` in `.profile` and Eclipse complains about missing `/usr/bin/ssh-askpass` make sure you don't have conflicts in your `.ssh/known_hosts`. For instance, try `git fetch` in a terminal in the same Git working copy and see if it complains about the host.

Answer (score 1):

No way! Sooo many years of eclipse out there and still no way to work with a `smartcards` and `ssh`/`ssh-agent`? Really disappointing come back to eclipse..

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=179924

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [cac-agent](https://github.com/MoebiusSolutions/cac-agent). It includes `cac-ssl-relay`, which can work as a universal tunnel from any client application that needs CAC access (including git/eclipse).